# JSONObject Creation throwing Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, json, nullpointerexception

I am in Android Studio, and I am trying to create an Android app that can do some networking. I can get some JSON data, but whenever I convert the String that I get to a `JSONObject`, a `NullPointerException` is thrown. Here is my Log error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
 at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
 at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
 at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
 at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
 at com.daita.getdusa.GetDataTask.doInBackground(GetDataTask.java:58)
 at com.daita.getdusa.GetDataTask.doInBackground(GetDataTask.java:21)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The line of code that is causing the exception is this:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
```

**Edit**

I was asked to put more source code, so here it is(The AsyncTask)

```
public class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
TextView submitView;
public GetDataTask(TextView submitView){
    this.submitView = submitView;
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    submitView.setText("Loading...");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    submitView.setText(s);

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    String result;
    result = getJSON("http://api.datausa.io/attrs/geo/");
    JSONArray data;
    List<String> parsedData = null;
    List<String> geoID = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        data = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
        parsedData = new ArrayList<>();
        Log.i("DUSA", String.valueOf(jsonObject.length()));
        for(int i=0; i < data.length(); i++){
            parsedData.add(data.getString(i));
        }
        for(String string: parsedData){
            //8, 9
            String[] dta = string.split(",");
            String populationResult = getJSON("http://api.datausa.io/api/?show=geo&sumlevel=all&required=pop&year=latest&geo="+dta[9].substring(1, dta[9].length()-1));
            if (result != null && result != "{\"error\": \"No tables can match the specified query.\"}") {
                JSONObject popObject = new JSONObject(populationResult);
                JSONArray popData = popObject.getJSONArray("data");
                String section = popData.getString(0);
                geoID.add(dta[8] + "," + dta[9] + "," + section);
            } else{
                geoID.add(dta[8] + "," + dta[9] + ", null");
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return geoID.toString();
}

public String getJSON(String url) {
    HttpURLConnection c = null;
    try {
        URL u = new URL(url);
        c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        c.connect();
        int status = c.getResponseCode();
        switch (status) {
            case 200:
            case 201:
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }
                br.close();
                return sb.toString();
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return ex.toString();
    } finally {
        if (c != null) {
            try {
                c.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Note: If you want real time source code updates, look at these  files https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5852rt2rakk6iii/AAAgjsqOTsFfP1N4kS1KzuTBa?dl=0

Comment: Can you add the Code and String.

Comment: Just add a null checker. That should be good. Also make sure that you are actually getting anything on the result. Also add the result code.

Comment: The null checker doesn't work. @PritamBanerjee

Comment: Could you be more specific? @sumandas

Comment: Sure, all we can see is some String str.length() returns null, so now if you are assigning some value to str from web call, static assignment, function call assignment etc, we are not sure. Null Check can avoid your issue but I am sure you want it to have some value which is not getting computed correctly, that is what we need to fix.

Comment: Just a QQ, if the result is not in JSON, can an NPE be thrown? @sumandas

Comment: Sure, it you declare something like this String str; and later try str = returnNullString( which returns null), and you try to compute str.length(), it would throw NPE.

Comment: Yeah, I tried the null check and an error check and I am still getting a problem.

Comment: I also think that if I try to use the Android Studio debugger, I will be able to find an issue. However, I am doing this in an AsyncTask. Do you know how to properly debug in an AsyncTask? Thank you. @sumandas

Comment: Is your json valid? Please check here. http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I have checked my JSON and it is valid. Even if my value is null, I get valid JSON. However, I remember once, I had an ArrayOutOfBoundsException after the NPE, so that might mean a thing or two. I really do not know how files run in an AsyncTask. Should I give you some more code? @sumandas

Comment: That would be good, and fyi async task is like thread, where the response received is notified to ui only in postExecute. Add code will see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121393/discussion-between-vicky-and-sumandas).

Comment: you have threading problem, you want to work with the JSON object which is not fetched yet

Comment: I would strongly suggest using Volley's `JsonObjectRequest`

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do it all for you, but let me go step by step to make it simpler for you:

```
package com.daita.getdusa;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by User on 8/12/2016.
 */
public class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{
    // Put in Main never here.
    String result;
    String allValues;
    Context context;
    public GetDataTask(Context mContext){
        this.context = mContext;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        ((TextView)((MainActivity)context).findViewById(R.id.resultView)).setText("Loading...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        ((TextView)((MainActivity)context).findViewById(R.id.resultView)).setText(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
        HttpURLConnection c = null;
        try {
            URL u = new URL("http://api.datausa.io/attrs/geo/"); // use urls first value
            c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            int status = c.getResponseCode();
            switch (status) {
                case 200:
                case 201:
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    br.close();
                    result = sb.toString();
                    getValue();
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                try {
                    c.disconnect();
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void getValue() {
        // FIX IT
        // Parse the JSON properly
    }

}
```

Now learn about json parsing, the data is huge, you need the response in smaller format this huge json, even crashes online json formatter. :)

This code works to show all of the json. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried your method, but it still isn't working. Do you think that I should do all of the JSONObject parsing stuff in onPostExecute? Sorry if I am giving you any trouble. @sumandas

Comment: Not an issue, yes you can do it there. Try to put the code in github for me to check it and see what is the issue.

Comment: Had trouble creating it in GitHub, but I made a link in Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5852rt2rakk6iii/AAAgjsqOTsFfP1N4kS1KzuTBa?dl=0  @sumandas

Comment: Found multiple issues, in async task, in connections etc. Will upload the basics.. and add details to answer, but fixes for the JSON you have to do it yourself :(

Comment: This will still cause the same NPE when then HttpURLConnection fails.

Comment: Issue is not with HttpURL but with Json Parsing and this being so huge a json, I am unable to see it in any notepad. So we have to reduce the response size by passing more specific query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Test {
 static String Json="{'root':{['ratedetails':{['levelOne':{["+ "{'FGROUP':'A','rentalpackage':'2D','NOOFDAYS':'2', 'HOURS':'0', 'PERIODPRICE':'100.00',"+ "'CUSTOMERPERDAY':'50.00', 'DRIVERPERDAY':'50.00' ,'KMALLOWANCE':'2', 'EXTKMALLOWPDAY':'60',"+ "'DRIVERKMCHARGE':'5', 'CUSTOMERKMCHARGE':'3', 'MAXIMUMKMCHARGE':'99999999', 'MAXKMCHRGTYPE':'0'"+",'HIDDEN':'2'},"+ "{'FGROUP':'A','rentalpackage':'2D','NOOFDAYS':'2', 'HOURS':'0', 'PERIODPRICE':'100.00',"+ "'CUSTOMERPERDAY':'50.00', 'DRIVERPERDAY':'50.00','KMALLOWANCE':'2', 'EXTKMALLOWPDAY':'60',"+ "'DRIVERKMCHARGE':'5', 'CUSTOMERKMCHARGE':'3', 'MAXIMUMKMCHARGE':'99999999', 'MAXKMCHRGTYPE':'0'"+",'HIDDEN':'2'}"+ "]}"+ "]}"+ "]}}";
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 //new Test().main();
 String s[]=Json.split(",");
 for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
{
 if(true){
 System.out.println(s[i].split(":")[s[i].split(":").length-2].substring(s[i].split(":")[s[i].split(":").length-2].indexOf("'")+1, s[i].split(":")[s[i].split(":").length-2].lastIndexOf("'"))+" "+ s[i].split(":")[s[i].split(":").length-1].substring(s[i].split(":")[s[i].split(":").length-1].indexOf("'")+1, s[i].split(":")[s[i].split(":").length-1].lastIndexOf("'")));
 }
else{
 System.out.println(s[i].split(":")[0].replace("'", "").trim()+" "+s[i].split(":")[1].replace("'", "").trim()); } } // System.out.println(Json.split(",")[5].split(":")[1].replace("'", "")); } }
```